# How to get the attributes of a PDF document in Xcode, e.g. version, total page numbers

Tags: xcode, macos, pdf

I try to make a PDF document manager for my own OSX by Xcode. Now I can get the URL of the document. With the code below:

```
NSOpenPanel *documentOpenPannel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
NSInteger situationInt = [documentOpenPannel runModal];

if (situationInt == NSOKButton) {
    NSURL *documentPath = [[documentOpenPannel URLs] lastObject];
}
```

From the documentPath, I can get some properties already, like file size:

```
NSString *fileSize;
[documentPath getResourceValue:&fileSize forKey:NSURLFileSizeKey error:nil];
```

Now I want to get more attributes of the documents, e.g. version number, total pages.

Could you give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`CGPDFDocument`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGPDFDocument/Reference/reference.html). `CGPDFDocumentGetVersion()`, `CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages()` solve your specific problem.